# html5 and css3 have gone absolutely wild and do things i have never seen before. There are 3 issues in total

Tags: html, css, web

I wanted to start creating a simple website and I am working on the navigation bar and the body now.

Here is the code and later on I will explain the issues.

```css
html {
  font-family: poppins, "Open Sans", "Inter", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-image: url("river-bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.navlink {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}

#navbar {
  float: right;
  padding: 3em;
}

.navlink:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

#p1 {
  float: right;
}

#p2 {
  float: right;
}

body {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 5em;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}

#main-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #00f100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<header>
  <div id="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="navlink" id="p1">page1</a>
    <a href="#" class="navlink" id="p2">page2</a>
  </div>
</header>

<div id="logospace"></div>

<body>
  <div id="main-content-wrapper">
    b
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

ISSUE 1:
The links are swapped, no matter what I did. Navigation link 1 and 2 are floated right, but navigation link 1 always ends up on the right, no matter how much I twist and turn the code.

ISSUE 2:
The navigation is clearly outside of the body but it still floats at the right side of the body and not of the entire html tag or the website.

ISSUE 3:
The body appears over the navigation bar, although it should definetely be under it.

This is driving me absolutely insane and i am looking for solutions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Content can either be inside `head` or `body` tag, otherwise, the browser displays some wacky output. Start with a proper code.

Comment: It can be useful to run code through a validator. I've just put yours through W3C's and it showed immediately that you have two body elements (in its view as it assumed one started after the head element).

Answer (score 0):

1. You have some elements outside of `<body></body>`
2. do you really need `float: right` for the inside the `.navbar`?
3. since you are using percentage dimensions for the body, you'll need specify size of it's parent `html` element as well.

```css
html {
  font-family: poppins, "Open Sans", "Inter", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-image: url("river-bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.navlink {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}

#navbar {
  float: right;
  padding: 3em;
}
.navlink:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
/*
#p1 {
  float: right;
}

#p2 {
  float: right;
}
*/
body {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 5em;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}

#main-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #00f100;
}


/* added */

#navbar {
  display: flex; /* removes gap between children */
}

html
{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
}
body
{
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="navbar">
      <a href="#" class="navlink" id="p1">page1</a>
      <a href="#" class="navlink" id="p2">page2</a>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div id="logospace"></div>

  <div id="main-content-wrapper">
    b
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```